# C# threading - Main Thread gets stuck in inf loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm running into a problem with my threading for my simple incremental game. 
when I begin the thread it does not seem to be starting an actual thread so I get stuck in the endless loop in the thread RunThread method.

the way I'm doing threading in c# is inheriting from this base thread class somebody else on SO gave this code to allow you to inherit from Thread.

```
abstract class BaseThread
{
    private Thread _thread;

    protected BaseThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.RunThread));
    }

    // Thread methods / properties
    public void Start() => _thread.Start();
    public void Join() => _thread.Join();
    public bool IsAlive => _thread.IsAlive;


    // Override in base class
    public abstract void RunThread();
    }
```

that base thread is then inherited from. Person inherits from Base Thread.

```
abstract class Person : BaseThread
{
    public BigInteger amt = new BigInteger(0);
    public BigInteger pow = new BigInteger(1);
    public BigInteger cost = new BigInteger(100);
    public ResourceManagement res= ResourceManagement.Instance;
    public static bool PeopleThreads = true;

    public override void RunThread()
    {

    }
 }
```

and at the lowest level, I have a Farmer this inherits from Person.

```
class Farmer : Person
{
    public override void RunThread()
    {
        while (PeopleThreads)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            res.AddFood(amt * pow);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            res.AddFood(amt * pow);
            res.subtractFromRes("Food", amt);
        }
    }
}
```

in my Thread manager class I am doing farmer.RunThread(); it seems to get me stuck in the while loop instead of creating a new thread. This is my first real attempt at c# threading ive done java threading before and thats why I wanted to be able to inherit from Thread. here is where I start my threads at.

```
class PeopleManager
{
    Farmer farmers = new Farmer();
    Lumberjack jacks = new Lumberjack();
    Miner miners = new Miner();
    private static PeopleManager people_Instance= new PeopleManager();
    bool running = false;

    static PeopleManager() { }//DO NOT PUT ANYTHING HERE
    private PeopleManager() { }//DO NOT PUT ANYTHING HERE
    public void StartThreads()
    {
        if (!running)
        {
            farmers.RunThread();
            jacks.RunThread();
            miners.RunThread();
            running = true;
        }            
    }

    public static PeopleManager Instance { get{ return people_Instance; } }
```

Comment: Seems a little contrived, though the `PeopleThreads` flag never gets set, ie the loop never stops. Instead of having your class control the thread, its probably better to make your class do what classes do, hold your concerns. and then if you need to thread it, use tasks when ever you need them

Comment: The PeopleThreads bool value is only so I can stop the thread later. this thread should run forever until I manually stop it

Comment: @TheGeneral is correct. look up single responsibility principle

Comment: What does the main thread code look like? Where do you start these threads?

Comment: you never start a new thread.  You create one, but never start it.

Comment: I added the code that starts the threads its at the end

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue changed how I was running the threads from runThread to Start()

```
class PeopleManager
{
Farmer farmers = new Farmer();
Lumberjack jacks = new Lumberjack();
Miner miners = new Miner();
private static PeopleManager people_Instance= new PeopleManager();
bool running = false;

static PeopleManager() { }//DO NOT PUT ANYTHING HERE
private PeopleManager() { }//DO NOT PUT ANYTHING HERE
public void StartThreads()
{
    if (!running)
    {
        farmers.Start(); //this instead of RunThread() made it run it 
        jacks.Start();   // run as a thread and not a method call
        miners.Start();   
        running = true;
    }            
}

public static PeopleManager Instance { get{ return people_Instance; } }
```